# Who tucked me in last night?

Tags: undertale

I was playing for the pacifist ending and was in the secret lab. Finding an empty bed, I decided to take a nap. A shape appeared and tucked me in. Who was it?

Video of the scene:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Who was that? That was an [Amalgamate](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Amalgamates). This Amalgamate is unnamed and appears in the pacifist router. By the looks of it, it's sole purpose is to tuck you in.

> An unnamed Amalgamate can tuck the protagonist into bed, should they decide to lay down in it and remain still for long enough. The Amalgamate then pats the protagonist on the head and disappears

While this Amalgamate may not have a name within the game itself, the sprite of the character within the game's data files is named *watchingman*

Answer (score -1):

That creature was something called an Amalgamate, as said above. That specific one was created only for that feature of the game.

If you wish to know more about them, this is the extent of what I know:
Amalgamates were deceased monsters that Alphys was trying to revive by infusing them with physical Determination. But, the experiment went wrong, turning the monsters into white-ish gray unidentifiable forms of their former selves. You fight them in a certain part of the game, can't remember where though. (It's either the core or the lab in hotland.)